# how to use django REST JWT authorization and authentication in class based views

Tags: authentication, permissions, django-rest-framework, authorization, django-rest-framework-jwt

I am using JWT authentication I am using this type of authorization app wide.

I am trying to figure out how to ue it in a view.

Example. Say I only want to allow a user to create an approved venue if they have the correct permissions. What would I add to this view to get access  to the user?

I know that django has `request.user` but how do I turn that on? Is it always on and request.user is null if there is no token passed into the header? Or is it middleware? The problem I am ultimately having is there is a lot of info getting to this point, but very little on actually using the JWT on the view.

please help.

```
# for creating an approved venue add ons later
class CreateApprovedVenue(CreateAPIView):
    queryset = Venue.objects.all()
    serializer_class = VenueSerializer
```

Django rest framework jwt docs 
https://jpadilla.github.io/django-rest-framework-jwt/

Django rest framework permissions docs 
http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/permissions/

so I discovered this resource and looking at it now. 
https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/how-to-authenticate-with-jwt-in-django--cms-30460

This example is sheading light:

```
# users/views.py
class CreateUserAPIView(APIView):
    # Allow any user (authenticated or not) to access this url 
    permission_classes = (AllowAny,)

    def post(self, request):
        user = request.data
        serializer = UserSerializer(data=user)
        serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
        serializer.save()
        return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To use JWT authentication, you need to do the following installation steps: https://jpadilla.github.io/django-rest-framework-jwt/#installation

Once that is done, you can include the auth by simply adding the `authentication_classes` as follows

```
# for creating an approved venue add ons later
class CreateApprovedVenue(CreateAPIView):
    authentication_classes = (JSONWebTokenAuthentication, )
    queryset = Venue.objects.all()
    serializer_class = VenueSerializer
```

And you have user available to you as `request.user` in all the request methods. In the case of the `CreateAPIView` you can do:

```
def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    user = request.user
    ...
```

Comment: how do I import the JSONWebTokenAuthentication tho ?

Comment: nevermind I got it `from rest_framework_jwt.authentication import JSONWebTokenAuthentication`